# What is an effective way to raise the water level on an entire world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to play in a water world with deep oceans and islands everywhere, not just occasional ocean biomes. I have looked for a good seed, but nothing really shows up. I am wondering if there is a way I can hack to flood an entire world. Is there an effective way of raising the water level across the entire world?

Comment: Answer:  Ya got a bucket?  >:D

Comment: Or get a thesaurus, and start exploring seeds! :) 1. Try lots of words. 2. See which world has huge oceans. 3. Post it on [Minecraft seeds](http://www.minecraftseeds.info/). 4. ??? 5. Profit!

Comment: 1335977250 is a seed that gives a water world in 1.8, but beware! There are no trees for days around the spawn. It's really only suitable for Creative mode.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is so beautiful. I loaded that seed and sure enough. There was nothing but water around my tiny little island for as far as I could see. Now trees will be an issue. I don't have to worry about reinstalling the mods now. :-)

Comment: Well, you level a bunch of land to create a bunch of settlers which will give you enough mana and you can then invoke the Flood power! This will raise the water level by one block across the entire map.  Oh, wait, you were asking about Minecraft.  Nevermind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try out the [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org) plugin called [Terrain Control](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/terrain-control/).  It features the ability to change the water height by modifying the config. However, you will have to [run a Bukkit server](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server) on your local network to use it.

As of snapshot [**14w17a**](https://mojang.com/2014/04/minecraft-snapshot-14w17a/), it is now possible to customize the water level ingame. When creating a new world, this can be achieved by clicking `More World Options...`, changing the `World Type` to `Customized`, and then selecting the `Customize` button. Here, you can change the sea level by moving the slider that says `Sea Level`, as well as many more options.

Comment: Do you know of a Bukkit plugin that will do it? "Probably" is not as specific and helpful as it could be.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So far I have not been able to find a Bukkit plugin, but I know that it is possible.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Just found one that appears to be able to change the height.

Comment: I looked these over and as far as I can tell only Terrain Control can change water level (using the `WaterLevelMax:64` variable). Terrain Control even says it's meant as a updated replacement for PhoenixTM.  I'll give you the bounty if you rewrite this answer to feature that plugin prominently!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Done.

Comment: Awesome! Enjoy your new rep, and check out the [FAQ] for what it all means.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Awesome, thanks for the help by putting a bounty on this question!

Comment: @LagAttack My pleasure! I love drowned worlds.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ha, I guess that makes two of us

Comment: Customized worlds were removed in 1.13

Answer (score 31):

***Update:** With the introduction of the ocean biome in beta 1.8, it is possible to play in a "water world" without needing to raise the sea level, by finding a seed which starts you in the middle of such a biome.  Seeds can be found wherever Minecraftians congregate, including [the official forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/50-seeds/) and [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftseeds).*

Even with a world editor, you cannot flood "the whole world", because the world is [procedurally generated](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World#Seeds) as you explore it.  The best you could get would be to flood the areas of the world you've already seen.

Instead, you should look for mods which affect world generation.  A quick search of [the mod forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/51-released-mods/) turns up the [Phoenix Terrain Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/313991-173-phoenixterrainmod-website-back-up), which has a `waterLevel` setting (default 64) as well as many others which may help you achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Good point about the procedurally generated world.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I set the water level to 80. I am now in a water world with islands every so often. I must say it is pretty cool. Thank you

Comment: With Poenix Terrain Mod now hopelessly out of date, an update to this answer would be wonderful, if only a suitable replacement mod or plugin could be found.

Answer (score 4):

The only possible way i can think of that might work for this is if you use the WorldEdit Mod, The only issue being though that this won't raise the properties for the actual world as i'm sure you've guessed. It'd be a very quick and easy way to modify the water levels in the immediate and surrounding areas though.

http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit

I hope you've got a few days spare, It's a hell of a mod to learn!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a water world by going into the superflat customization screen (**Create World > More world option... > World type: Superflat > Customize**) and then choosing the "Water World" preset. Note that this will generate villages, so you might be able to get some wood and stuff by doing some diving. Have fun!

Comment: It will have a flat ocean bottom and no islands. The question isn't asking for *that kind* of water world.

Answer (score 1):

There is a naturally generated survival island world that I play on occasionally. The seed is "Sprite". the S is capitalized.

Comment: Which version of MineCraft is that for? Every time they make changes to the terrain generation, the old seeds become "invalid" (or rather, they generate completely different terrain).

Comment: This worked the last time I used it, but that was about a month ago. This may no longer be valid. I will try to check tonight. If it doesn't work, I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a customized world, and on the FIRST PAGE, and the FIRST SETTING, there will be a slider bar that lets you change the sea level. I seem to be the only one that can figure this out.

Comment: Except for, you know the first answer on the page that says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in a snapshot before 1.8 there was a cusomize world option where you could just make a world to your specifications

Answer (score -1):

Use world painter http://www.worldpainter.net/ and make a world with lots of islands